# What is preventing my async code from running async?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I'm trying to leave threads and start using async. I tried to write something simple so I can get more comfortable with async; for some reason my async code isn't acting async.

I rewrote the same code in threads and it worked fast and concurrently, unlike the async code.

Normal code

```py
import time 
import random

def display(x: int) -> None:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 8))
    print(x)

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        display(i) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Async code

```py
import time 
import random
import asyncio

async def display(x: int) -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 8))
    print(x)

async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        await display(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
    event_loop.close()
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Thread code

```py
import time 
import random 
import threading 

def display(x: int) -> None:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 8))
    print(x)

def main():
    threads = []

    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=display, args=[i])
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
5
9
3
0
4
2
1
8
6
7
```

Answer (score 1):

`await display(i)` runs `display` with argument `i`, which returns an **awaitable**. You then immediately wait for it with `await`, blocking the call right there.

If you want to schedule them all together and then wait at the end, you need to collect the awaitables in a list and then wait for all of them at once.

```
import time
import random
import asyncio

async def display(x: int) -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 8)/10)
    print(x)

async def main():
    awaitables = []
    for i in range(10):
        awaitables.append(display(i))
    await asyncio.wait(awaitables)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
    event_loop.close()
```

---

And yes, because otherwise someone will surely point it out, you can also write that in a list comprehension:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([display(i) for i in range(10)])
```

---

Further note:

I'm sure you are aware, nonetheless I think it is important to mention it anyway. The code runs *asynchronous*, but not *parallel*. Running multiple compution-heavy functions with `async` or `threading.Thread` still only runs them on one single cpu core without any speedup. The Python interpreter is single-threaded.